# import and export using impdp/expdp in oracle10g/11g

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g, datapump

I have two databases, one is production and second is a test. I want to export from production database and import into test database.
My production db contains many users/schema out of which only few (<10) schemas contain actual objects. 
First time, i did a successful full export and full import into my test system without any problem.

The idea is to do this on a periodic basis maybe once in couple of weeks. How can i do this process without creating a whole new test database again doing the re-import??

Answer (score 1):

In `impdp` there is the option to import data only using `CONTENT=DATA_ONLY`
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm

Also have a look at `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION` (which already defaults to `APPEND` if using `DATA_ONLY`)